# bug when loading file with googlesheets4::read_sheet()

Tags: r

I'm not able to load a Google sheet by using the following command:

```
googlesheet4::read_sheet(url)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) :attempt to apply non-function
```

It worked yesterday on R version 4.1.2 but since upgrading to version 4.1.3 I started getting this error.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards,
Obakeng

Comment: Update your packages. Attention this will update all your packages withiout asking: `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Tarjae, I tried that but the problem still persists.  seems all googlesheet4 functions yield the same error.